# What do curly brackets inside a function in JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curly-braces

I'm wondering what curly brackets do inside a function.
I was checking lazy() which is one of function in React library, and found code like this:

```
function lazy(x) {
    var payload = {//some values};
    var lazyType = {//some values}; 
    {   // ???
         var defaultProps;
         var proptype;
         Object.defineProperties(lazyType, {
             defaultProps: {//codes}
             },
             propTypes: {//codes}
         });
    }  // ???
return lazyType;
}
```

I'm not sure how those curly brackets work or mean..
please help me to understand, thank you

Comment: It's a statement block. In this particular case it is useless, but it can be useful when you use blockscoped variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I could find what i was looking for and understand.
Thank you very much!!